# onAnimationEnd() called twice

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-8.1-oreo

After updating the build sdk 27 from 23 came across this issue of onAnimationEnd firing twice in the code below when called. onAnimationStart is called only once and onAnimationRepeat is not called as expected. Now in the app when the user presses the back button one time, they are taken two steps back.

All the libraries in gradle are using 27.0.2 which is the latest. This code used to work fine in sdk 23. Our min target is 16.

I'm using a work around by using a isAnimating flag but would like to find the underlying cause which could be affecting other areas of the app.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        Animation slideOutRightAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        slideOutRightAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        slideOutRightAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                isAnimating = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if(isAnimating) { // Fix
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }
                isAnimating = false;
            }
        });
        fragmentToPopView.clearAnimation();
        fragmentToPopView.startAnimation(slideOutRightAnimation);
```

Comment: Can you make sure `onBackPressed()` is *not* called twice?

Comment: It's not, I tried setting breakpoints in onBackPressed() and onAnimationStart(). They both only get called one time. Also should mention that this code was working fine in SDK 23.

Comment: what do you see in both cases when you add `Thread.dumpStack()` insode `onAnimationEnd` method?

Comment: @pskink https://gist.github.com/chris-gunawardena/374ea9a2d46bb1ce70145eee59d76959

Comment: tried to `Log.d` the value of `animation.toString()` ? or just `animation.hashCode()` inside `onAnimationEnd`? are they really the same?

Comment: animationStart(), and the two animationEnd() all three log the same toString() value: android.view.animation.AnimationSet@a7da5f00 and the same hash code  -1486792280

Comment: what are timestamps when those two `animationEnd` occur? try to `Log.d` the value of `System#currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @pskink 01-21 08:10:44.031 E/x: onAnimationStart: 1516522244043, 
01-21 08:10:44.301 E/x:  onAnimationEnd: 1516522244311. 
01-21 08:10:44.441 E/x:  onAnimationEnd: 1516522244454

Comment: I tried creating a fresh project with the same sdk but it's working fine, so the issue is in my project somewhere. https://gist.github.com/chris-gunawardena/e4ee2d705ddd8ed285e6e4ddc7beb177

Comment: hmmm, even more strange... tried tor completely remove `build` folder and run again?

Comment: No luck, Thank you for your help, Monday I'll try move back to sdk 26 or 25 and update all the dependencies to match and report back. This is the list of deps if it helps: https://gist.github.com/chris-gunawardena/66892eadcac5f307b94bd2c348d204b2

Answer (score 5):

Removing the old listener on the `onAnimationEnd` will solve your problem.

```
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            slideOutRightAnimation.setAnimationListener(null);
            // ... //
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try it

Before start animation

fragmentToPopView.clearAnimation();

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: When I call startAnimation() I want onAnimationEnd to be called one time. At the moment it's called twice every time for startAnimation()

Comment: I thing you want slide right to left screen onbackpressed?